# CPAN module installation failure

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm trying to install **POE::Component:IRC::State** but keep returning this error. I've tried googling but no solutions. Anyone know how to handle this?

```
install POE::Component:IRC::State
Going to read '/home/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 22 Jul 2014 11:41:02 GMT
Running install for module 'POE::Component::IRC::State'
Running make for B/BI/BINGOS/POE-Component-IRC-6.88.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/user/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/POE-Component-IRC-6.88.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/user/.cpan/build for sizes
Use of uninitialized value $newdir in substitution (s///) at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/Cwd.pm line 502.
Use of uninitialized value $newdir in chdir at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/Cwd.pm line 510.
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/Cwd.pm line 510.
Use of uninitialized value $newdir in pattern match (m//) at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/Cwd.pm line 525.
Use of uninitialized value $newdir in split at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/Cwd.pm line 531.
............................................................................DONE

Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in join or string at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/File/Spec/Unix.pm line 86.
Use of uninitialized value $path in pattern match (m//) at /opt/OMNIperl/lib/5.14/i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64/File/Spec/Unix.pm line 267.


  CPAN.pm: Going to build B/BI/BINGOS/POE-Component-IRC-6.88.tar.gz

Warning: No success on command[/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL]
  BINGOS/POE-Component-IRC-6.88.tar.gz
  /opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
 BINGOS/POE-Component-IRC-6.88.tar.gz         : writemakefile NO '/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL' returned status -1
```

Comment: `Warning: No success on command[/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL]` what happens when you run this manually?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to this, how do I run it manually?

Comment: Is `perl` trying to build a dependency that needs a compiler (clang, gcc)? Is there one available on the machine? To run the command as Dr. Avalanche mentioned just do: `/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL`

Comment: `cpan[8]> /opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL
Unknown shell command '/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl'. Type ? for help.`

Comment: Exit `cpan` tool. `cd ~/.cpan/build/POE-Component-IRC-*` (or choose one of matching directories if more match). Then try to re-run `/opt/OMNIperl/bin/amd64/perl Makefile.PL`.

Comment: @buff: or you can use cpan's `look` command to start a shell in the unpacked distribution's dir

Comment: it gave me this: `Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for POE::Component::IRC
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across something similar to this before and I believe the reason for your error, assuming you are receiving this error for other modules installations as well*, is that you need to update your current version of Perl.

From your error report it seems that you are running 5.14 but you should be running 5.20 instead. If this is a remote/personal set up, you can try upgrading your version of Perl but definitely back up everything.

If this is part of a larger system, I would highly advise contacting your system administrator and asking them to look into the problem and have them upgrade it. It is a very sensitive action and upgrading can affect a bunch of other programs you have on your servers.